# Dart Regex for alphanumeric, including dashes and spaces but not blank String

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to implement a regex in Dart to ensure that a string is a max of 20 chars, alphanumeric but can include spaces and dashes, and can also not be empty. I've tried a few different solutions but can't get it to honor the negative lookahead for "blank string". This is what I have now:

```
^(?!\s*\$)[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{1,20}\$
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If there can not be consecutive dashes or spaces and not at the start or end you can assert 1-20 chars  `^(?=.{1,20})[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/gxpVH1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have escaped the `$` signs so instead of indicating the end of the line, it will instead use the letter "$" which I am sure you don't want. Try this instead:

```
RegExp(r'^(?!\s*$)[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{1,20}$');
```

I can recommend trying and debugging RegExp's by using a site like this which is good to explain each part of the parsing: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Ah crap, I did not notice that. Thanks!